# How to calculate $\int_{\partial B_2(0)}\frac{2z^2+7z+11}{z^3+4z^2-z-4}\;dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

I want to calculate $$\displaystyle\int_{\partial B_2(0)}\underbrace{\frac{2z^2+7z+11}{z^3+4z^2-z-4}}_{=:f(z)}\;dz\tag{0}$$ [Partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) yields $$f(z)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{z+4}}_{=:f_1(z)}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{z+1}}_{=:f_2(z)}+\underbrace{\frac{2}{z-1}}_{=:f_3(z)}\tag{1}$$ From this representation of $f$, it's easy to see that $-4$ and $\pm 1$ are [poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29) of $f$. That means, that we can't take benefit from [Cauchy's integral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), since $f$ is unbounded in a neighborhood of one of these poles.

However, since $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{-4,\pm 1\right\}$ we can apply the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) which states here $$\int_{\partial B_2(0)}f(z)\;dz=2\pi i\sum_{z_0\in\left\{-4,\pm 1\right\}}\text{res}(f,z_0)\;\text{ind}_{\partial B_2(0)}\text{ }z_0$$ The winding number of $-4$ is obvious equal to $0$ while that ones of $\pm 1$ are equal to $1$.

---

So, what would be smart to do now? Either we consider $f$ as a whole or as the sum of $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$:

1. In the first case, we would need to calculate the integrals $$\int_{\partial B_{\delta_\pm}(\pm 1)}f(z)\;dz$$ with $B_{\delta_\pm}(\pm 1)\subset B_2(0)$
2. In the second case, we would need to determine the Laurent series expansion of $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ at $\pm 1$. We can take advantage of the fact, that $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ in $(1)$ are in their Laurent series form at $-4$, $-1$ and $1$, respectively.

**What would be the easier way? Is there some rule of thumb in general?**

It seems like in this case, both options are too complicated and it would be easier to calculate $(0)$ from the definition without the residue theorem. **Or is there something what prevents me from doing this?**

---

Notes:

- $B_r(z_0):=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-z_0|<r\right\}$
- $A_{r,R}(z_0):=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:r<|z-z_0|<R\right\}$
- $\text{ind}_{\gamma}\text{ }z_0$ is the [winding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of $z_0$ wrt $\gamma$

Comment: When you already have the partial fraction decomposition, you can directly read off the residues from that. Note that $f \mapsto \operatorname{res}(f,z_0)$ is linear, and $\operatorname{res}\left(\frac{1}{z-z_1}, z_0\right) = 0$ for $z_1 \neq z_0$. So $$\int_{\partial B_2(0)} \frac{2z^2+7z+11}{z^3+4z^2-z-4}\,dz = 2\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}\left(\frac{2}{z-1},1\right) - \operatorname{res}\left(\frac{1}{z+1},-1\right)\right) = 2\pi i(2-1) = 2\pi i,$$ you don't need to develop any of the fractions into a Taylor series around one of the other poles.

Comment: @DanielFischer So, we've always got $$\operatorname{res}\left(\frac{\alpha}{z-z_0},z_0\right)=\alpha\;,$$ right? $$$$ There is another thing I stumbled about: If we're looking at a path integral of a function which has a pole (or an other singularity) at $z_0$ and we're integrating along a path whose trace intersects $z_0$; do we need to pay attention to this situation?

Comment: Right. And we absolutely need to pay attention when a singularity lies on the path of integration. If a branch-cut intersects the path transversally, the integral exists, but you can't simply use the residue theorem to evaluate it. If a branch point lies on the path, but the branch-cut lies completely outside the contour, you can use the residue theorem to evaluate the integral over a slightly deformed path avoiding the branch point, and get the result of the original by continuity. If a pole lies on the path, the integral does not exist as an improper Riemann or a Lebesgue integral, but if

Comment: the pole is simple, it is typically useful to interpret the integral as a principal value integral. If the pole has higher order, but the principal part contains only odd powers of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$, you can also interpret the integral as a principal value integral, but that is rarely interesting, only simple poles are of greater interest. If the principal part contains even powers, the integral doesn't exist, and you cannot rescue the situation by considering it as a principal value integral. If there is an essential singularity on the path, whether the integral exists or not depends on the path

Comment: but generally, such an occurrence means you shouldn't have looked at that integral at all.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your great and detailed explanation.

Comment: @DanielFischer One further question: Do we have $$\operatorname{res}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\left( z-z_0\right)^n},z_1\right)=\begin{cases}\alpha &\text{, if }z_1=z_0\\0 &\text{, else}\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\left(n\in\mathbb{N}\right),$$ too?

Comment: For $n \neq 1$, we always have $$\operatorname{res}\left(\frac{\alpha}{(z-z_0)^n}, z_1\right) = 0,$$ regardless of whether $z_0 = z_1$ or not. Only terms of the form $\frac{\alpha}{(z-z_0)^1}$ can give a (nonzero) residue.

Comment: @DanielFischer What if we're considering $$g(z):=\frac{e^{z^2}}{(z+1)^3(z+2)}=e^{z^2}\left\{\underbrace{\frac{1}{z+1}}_{=:g_1(z)}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{(z+1)^2}}_{=:g_2(z)}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{(z+1)^3}}_{=:g_3(z)}-\frac{1}{z+2}\right\}$$ and $$\int_{\partial B_2(-2)}g(z)\;dz$$ The winding numbers of $-1$ and $-2$ are $1$ and $0$, respectively. We need to calculate $$\operatorname{res}\left(e^{z^2}g_k(z),-1\right)$$ for all $k$. From wolfram Alpha I know, the results will be $e$, $-2$ and $3e$. But how do I proceed here? $$-$$ [I've no idea why the last "underbrace" is broken here]

Comment: The winding number of $\partial B_2(-2)$ is $1$ for both, $z = -1$ and $z = -2$. For the residues of $\frac{e^{z^2}}{z+k}$, you just evaluate $e^{z^2}$ in $-k$. For the residue of $\frac{e^{z^2}}{(z+1)^m}$, you evaluate the $(m-1)^{\text{st}}$ derivative of $e^{z^2}$ in $-1$ and divide by $(m-1)!$.

Comment: @DanielFischer [$-2$ lies on the border of $\partial B_2(-2)$ - shouldn't it's winding number equal $0$?] Last question: Consider some more fancy path like in $$\int_{\partial R}\underbrace{\exp\frac{1}{z}\cos\frac{1}{z}}_{=:h(z)}\;dz$$ where $R$ is the rectangle induced by the points $-2-i$, $3-i$, $3+2i$ and $-2+2i$ and $h$ obviously has an elementary singularity at $0$. Is there something which prevents me from simply integrate over $[-2-i,3-i]$, $[3-i,3+2i]$, $[3+2i,-2+2i]$ and $[-2+2i,-2-i]$? [I've always wondered how exactly I need to deal with signs when adding up the partial results].

Comment: No, $-2$ is the centre of $B_2(-2)$. Were you thinking of $B_2(0)$? Then it would be on the boundary, which means the winding number is not defined. If you regard it as a principal value integral, since the pole is simple, the end effect is that the pole lies "half inside and half outside the contour (as the path doesn't have a corner; for corners, the fraction would be proportional to the angle)". For the rectangle, the only thing preventing you from performing the integration as indicated is the unfriendliness of the integrand. In reality, you'd evaluate the integral per the residue theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer [You're right, I was thinking about $B_2(0)$] Please explain the "reality" to me ;) How would I use the residue theorem for this purpose?

Comment: $$\int_{\partial R} \exp \frac{1}{z}\cos \frac{1}{z}\,dz = 2\pi i \operatorname{res}\left(\exp \frac{1}{z}\cos \frac{1}{z}, 0\right).$$ Now since the Laurent series of both factors contain no positive powers of $z$, you can evaluate the residue simply by looking at the Laurent series, $$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2z^2} + \dotsc\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{2z^2} + \frac{1}{24z^4}-\dotsc\right) = 1 + \frac{1}{z} + O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right),$$ so the residue is $1$. it would be more challenging to find the integral of $\exp\frac{1}{z}\cos z$ for example. But then, multiplying the series to

Comment: find the residue (expressed as a series) would most likely still be easier than integrating.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm a little bit surprised: You didn't used the concrete shape of the rectangle, did you?

Comment: No. The point of the residue theorem and its special cases (integral formula, integral theorem, argument principle) is that the integral is invariant under continuous deformations of the contour that meet no singularity. So if there are only isolated singularities, all that matters is how often the contour winds around each, and what the residue there is. In this case, we have a contour winding once around the sole singularity in $0$. So the integral is $2\pi i$ times the residue.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've got a much better understanding of this, than before, but I still got troubles when dealing with new examples: $$\int_{\underbrace{\partial B_{10}(0)}_{=:\gamma}}\overbrace{\sin\frac 1{z-2}+\frac{2\sin z-3z}z+\underbrace{\frac 1{z^2+4}}_{=:g(z)}}^{=:f(z)}dz$$ $g$ has first-order poles at $\pm 2i$, $\text{ind}_\gamma (\pm 2i)=1$ and

Comment: $$\text{res}(f,\pm 2i)=\overbrace{\text{res}\left(\sin\frac 1{z-2},\pm 2i\right)}^{\stackrel{(*)}{=0}}+2\overbrace{\text{res}\left(\frac{\sin z}z,\pm 2i\right)}^{\stackrel{(*)}{=0}}-\overbrace{\text{res}(3,\pm 2i)}^{\stackrel{(*)}{=0}}+\overbrace{\text{res}\left(\frac 1{z^2+4},\pm 2i\right)}^{(**)}$$ The functions marked with $(*)$ are holomorphic in a neighborhood of $\pm 2i$, so their residues at these points equals $0$. For the function marked with $(**)$, we've got: $$\text{res}\left(\frac 1{z^2+4},\pm 2i\right)=\lim_{z\to\pm 2i}\frac{z\mp 2i}{z^2+4}=\mp \frac i{4}$$ So, I think we have

Comment: $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\;dz=2\pi i\left\{\frac i{4}-\frac i{4}\right\}=0$$ However, Wolfram Alpha yields $-6.28319+6.28319i$ as the the value of the integral.

Comment: You forgot the essential singularity of $\sin \frac{1}{z-2}$ in $2$. The residue there is $1$, so the integral ought to be $2\pi i$. Why Wolfram Alpha evaluated it as $(2\pi i)(1+i)$, I don't see. I suspect you had a typo in your input, for WA should be able to compute that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are already in their laurent series form. You can just read off the residues.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of Cauchy's Integral formula yields:

$\displaystyle\int_{\partial B_2(0)}-\frac{1}{z+1}\;dz=-2\pi i$ and $\displaystyle\int_{\partial B_2(0)}\frac{2}{z-1}\;dz=4\pi i$